# What's wrong with my code? Power BI says some specific columns can not be found such as: "Textbox13" :(

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("E:\After Sales\TAT Dashboards\TAT Ver2 - Copy"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text},{"Textbox13", Int64.Type}, {"DCName", type text}, {"Serialnumber", type text}, {"ItemID", Int64.Type}, {"ItemName", type text}, {"return_request_create_date", type datetime}, {"return_request_create_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"return_request_approved_date", type datetime}, {"return_request_approved_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Order_number", Int64.Type}, {"Nature", type text}, {"Inbound_agent", type text}, {"Processed_by", type text}, {"Processed_at", type datetime}, {"Processed_at_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"assign_tech_user", type text}, {"Inbound_date", type datetime}, {"Inbound_date_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Last_status", type text}, {"Last_status_date", type any}, {"Last_status_date_Shamsi", type any}, {"Warehouse_agent", type text}, {"Basket_id", Int64.Type}, {"Return_request_ID", Int64.Type}, {"Request_Source", type text}, {"Return_Reason", type text}, {"Warehouse_outbound_date", type datetime}, {"Warehouse_outbound_date_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"outbound_type", type text}, {"Pickup_type", type text}, {"drivername", type text}, {"Destination_Distribution_Center", type text}, {"Source_Distribution_Center", type text}, {"payment_date", type datetime}, {"payment_date_shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Date", type text}, {"Shipment_Scope_Start", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Scope_End", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Status", type text}, {"complete_pick_up_date", type datetime}, {"complete_pick_up_date_shamsi", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([DCName] <> "")),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Inbound_date", "Inbound_date - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Inbound_date - Copy", type time}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Inbound_date - Copy", "Inbound Times"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"delivery_date_time", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type2", each ([payment_date] <> null)),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Promised_date", type datetime}, {"Inbound Times", type time}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type3", {"Warehouse_outbound_date_Shamsi"}, DATES, {"Jalali_4"}, "DATES", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded DATES" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "DATES", {"JWeekNum"}, {"DATES.JWeekNum"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded DATES",{{"selling_price", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type4"
```

Answer (score -1):

it means exactly what is written there, a column named "Textbox13" is missing, it is used in the #"Change Type" step.

Why is it broken now? has it been renamed in the source? has it been removed from the source? nobody will ever know except you...

Below the code without reference to that column

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("E:\After Sales\TAT Dashboards\TAT Ver2 - Copy"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"DCName", type text}, {"Serialnumber", type text}, {"ItemID", Int64.Type}, {"ItemName", type text}, {"return_request_create_date", type datetime}, {"return_request_create_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"return_request_approved_date", type datetime}, {"return_request_approved_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Order_number", Int64.Type}, {"Nature", type text}, {"Inbound_agent", type text}, {"Processed_by", type text}, {"Processed_at", type datetime}, {"Processed_at_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"assign_tech_user", type text}, {"Inbound_date", type datetime}, {"Inbound_date_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Last_status", type text}, {"Last_status_date", type any}, {"Last_status_date_Shamsi", type any}, {"Warehouse_agent", type text}, {"Basket_id", Int64.Type}, {"Return_request_ID", Int64.Type}, {"Request_Source", type text}, {"Return_Reason", type text}, {"Warehouse_outbound_date", type datetime}, {"Warehouse_outbound_date_Shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"outbound_type", type text}, {"Pickup_type", type text}, {"drivername", type text}, {"Destination_Distribution_Center", type text}, {"Source_Distribution_Center", type text}, {"payment_date", type datetime}, {"payment_date_shamsi", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Date", type text}, {"Shipment_Scope_Start", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Scope_End", Int64.Type}, {"Shipment_Status", type text}, {"complete_pick_up_date", type datetime}, {"complete_pick_up_date_shamsi", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([DCName] <> "")),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Inbound_date", "Inbound_date - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Inbound_date - Copy", type time}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Inbound_date - Copy", "Inbound Times"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"delivery_date_time", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type2", each ([payment_date] <> null)),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Promised_date", type datetime}, {"Inbound Times", type time}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type3", {"Warehouse_outbound_date_Shamsi"}, DATES, {"Jalali_4"}, "DATES", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded DATES" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "DATES", {"JWeekNum"}, {"DATES.JWeekNum"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded DATES",{{"selling_price", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type4"
```